# Filter R data.table based on groupings created using cumulative sum of a column

Tags: r, filter, data.table, cumsum

I need an efficient data.table solution to filter to just the first and last instance for each 300 of a cumulative sum of a column. My real dataset is millions rows, so I am NOT looking for a looped solution.

```
#Example data:
  dt <- data.table(idcolref=c(1:1000),y=rep(10,1000))
```

An example loop that does what I'd like is below, but it is far too slow to be useful for a large data.table.

```
###example of a loop that produces the result I want but is too slow
  library(foreach)
  dt[,grp:=1,]
  dt[,cumsum:=0,]
  grp <- 1
  foreach(a=2:nrow(dt))%do%{
    dt[a,"cumsum"]<-dt[a,"y"]+dt[a-1,"cumsum"]
    if(dt[a,"cumsum"]>300){
      dt[a,"grp"] <- grp
      grp <- grp+1
      dt[a,"cumsum"]<-0
    }else{
      dt[a,"grp"]<-dt[a-1,"grp"]
    }
  }
  dt.desired <- foreach(a=2:nrow(dt),.combine=rbind)%do%{
    if(dt[a,"grp"]!=dt[a-1,"grp"]){
      dt[c(a-1,a),]
    }
  }
  dt.desired <- rbind(dt[1,],dt.desired)
  dt.desired <- rbind(dt.desired,dt[nrow(dt),])
```

How can I get the same result using fast vectorized data.table functions? Thanks!

Comment: x is your group?

Comment: No, I need to generate the group based on x (or y)

Comment: can you be more clear, which is your id column?

Comment: Are you sure your `dt.desired` is correct? if you put an index column on `dt[, id := .I]` it suggests the first group is rows 1 and 122. ?

Comment: why is the first value of your output 0? shouldn't it 10?

Comment: I think there are some mistakes in your example code. First there is no column `x` in your data, second I am not sure if the result is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've interpreted your requirement correctly:

1. you want to calculate the cumulative sum of a vector (column).
2. If the cumulative sum gets to 300 you want to reset it back to 0.
3. Each time you reset to 0, you want to say those values of the vector are in a new group.
4. You want to select the first and last rows of each group

If this is the case, you can write your own fast 'vectorised' function in `Rcpp`

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(x=rep(5,1e7),y=rep(10,1e7))
## adding a row index to keep track of which rows are returned
dt[, id := .I]

library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('Rcpp::NumericVector findGroupRows(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {

  int cumsum = 0;
  int grpCounter = 0;
  size_t n = x.length();
  Rcpp::NumericVector groupedCumSum(n);

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cumsum += x[i];
    if (cumsum > 300) {
      cumsum = 0;
      grpCounter++;
    }
    groupedCumSum[i] = grpCounter;
  }
  return groupedCumSum;
}')

dt[, grp := findGroupRows(y)]

dt[ dt[, .I[c(1, .N)], by = grp]$V1]
```

Comment: That `dt[ dt[, .I[c(1, .N)], by = grp2]$V1]` is pretty neat. Your groups are off by one element though (31 members instead of 30)

Comment: cpp is amazingly fast for this. Nice.

Comment: @StefanF - are you sure I'm off by one element?

Comment: @NealBarsch - yep. Worth bearing in mind that 'vectorisation' is pretty much a loop written in a compiled language, usually `C`, `C++` or `fortran`

Comment: try `table(dt[, .N[[1]], by = "grp"]$V1)`, at least on my machine it gives me the wrong size (the first group is 30 elements, all following one except the last are 31). I had the reverse issue with my original solution before i edited it (e.g my first group was to small).

Comment: I think the error is `cumsum = 0`, it should be `cumsum = x[i]`

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using only `data.table` and base R functions:

```
dt[, grp2 := (cumsum(y) - 1) %/% 300]  

# straight forward solution:
dt[, .SD[c(1, .N)], by = "grp"]

# more efficient for large datasets, as suggested by SymbolixAU
dt[ dt[, .I[c(1, .N)], by = "grp"]$V1]

# check if your groups are of the correct size
table(dt[, .N[[1]], by = "grp"]$V1)
```

- `%/%` is the integer division operator
- `.SD` is current the subset of  the `data.table` by group
- `.N` is the number of rows in the current
  subset (identical to `nrow(.SD`))
- the `-1` ensures the correct size for the first group